Cannot adjust brightness on windows 11 laptop
I cannot adjust the brightness of the screen manually both by moving the cursor from the brightness bar or by using shortcut keys. It remained on 100% brightness. I have tried rebooting the laptop, but to no avail. I also tried updating, disabling and then enabling, unistalling the graphics and the GPU drivers and it still did not work. Another thing that I thought it would work was to reset the BIOS but it did not help much. I finally tried to change NVIDIA Display Container LS from Manual to Automatic. I do not know how to sort this issue out. However, the night light still works.

Start by updating UEFI and troubleshoot from there.

What laptop? Be specific.
